# Oracle DB 12r2 java source locale issue

Tags: java, oracle, locale, oracle12c

I have issue in Oracle DB 12r2 (win64 with 12.2.0.1.180417 patchset) with locale usage in java source.

Action to reproduce:

```
-- Java source
create or replace and compile java source named tmp_j as
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class tmp_j
{

private static String byLocale(Locale loc) {
  Locale.setDefault(loc);
  DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,##0.00");
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
  return  numberFormat.format(123456.789)+" "+dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
  public static String entry()
  {
    return System.getProperty("java.version")+" "+System.getProperty("file.encoding")+
           " EN="+byLocale(Locale.US)+
           " FR="+byLocale(Locale.FRENCH)+
           " RU="+byLocale(new Locale("ru","RU"));
  }
}
/

-- Function for it
create or replace function f_tmp_j
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'tmp_j.entry()
      return java.lang.String';
/

--Execute:
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(f_tmp_j);
end;
/
```

In 12r2 I get:

```
1.8.0_171 WINDOWS-1251
EN=123,456.79 20 Apr 2018
FR=123,456.79 20 Apr 2018
RU=123,456.79 20 Apr 2018
```

It is unexpected value, because format locales are always English, and not French or Russian!

In 12r1:

```
1.6.0_81 WINDOWS-1251
EN=123,456.79 20 Apr 2018
FR=123 456,79 20 avr. 2018
RU=123 456,79 20 апр 2018
```

In plain java 8:

```
1.8.0_171 UTF-8
EN=123,456.79 20 Apr 2018
FR=123 456,79 20 avr. 2018
RU=123 456,79 20 апр 2018
```

So 12r2 has unexpected behaiour or may be bug.

NLS paramepers are the same in 12r1 and 12r2:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET=CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_LANGUAGE=RUSSIAN
NLS_TERRITORY=RUSSIA
```

Searching Google and Oracle Support has no result.

Can anyone reproduce in your 12r2 environment? Any ideas to solve?

Thank you!

Comment: *"Any ideas to solve?"* Specify the locale explicitly on the formatters, e.g. `new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,##0.00", new DecimalFormatSymbols(loc))` and `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", loc)`, instead of relying on the platform default. --- Don't call `Locale.setDefault`. If needed, the platform default locale should be specifies externally, before the JVM is started.

Comment: I understand and tried to use locale as parameter, but result is same: 12r2 uses English locale, ignoring parameter.